# HTML 5 mode deep link and refresh not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, pretty-urls

I am using ng-viewport  to display my pages in the index.html, in HTML 5 mode everything is working fine when we open the base url (e.g. http://localhost:86 ), which loads and get onverted to (http://localhost:86/app/dashboard ) which is my home or landing page, and all the other re-directions works properly .

The problem arises when we directly try to open the complete URL (e.g. http://localhost:86/app/dashboard ), it is loading my index.html page, but displaying only static content like logo, and images, and not showing my dynamic web pages which are shown in ng-viewport section. There is a same behavior on reload of any page.

Following is code which I have wrote.

JS code.

> `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true });`

HTML code

```
<head>
    <base href="/"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img class="rotate" src="../assets/img/logo_img.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%" ng-viewport autoscroll>
    </div>
</body>
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
      <files>
         <clear />
         <add value="index.html" />
         <add value="Default.htm" />
         <add value="Default.asp" />
         <add value="index.htm" />
         <add value="iisstart.htm" />
         <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
   </defaultDocument>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <hiddenSegments>
            <remove segment="App_Data" />
         </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
         <clear />
         <rule name="AngularJS" enabled="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(Api)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
         </rule>
      </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Route config code

```
static $routeConfig = [{
        path: '/dashboard/:type',
        component: 'dashboard'
    }, {
        path: '/dashboard',
        component: 'dashboard'
    }, {
        path: '/mail',
        component: 'mail'
    }, {
        path: '/solution/:id',
        component: 'solutionDetails'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the relative and absolute path of my js and css files.
I have added / in front of my all file paths which I am loading in index.html, and now everything works like a charm.

```
**Earlier :**  <script src="app.js"></script>

**Now:**  <script src="/app.js"></script>
```